# extdirectspring methods not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, extjs, ext-direct

I set up ext direct for my Spring MVC app using [extdirectspring](http://code.google.com/p/extdirectspring/). I am able to retrieve primitives and Strings and use them in ext.js. When I try to retrieve a list of objects, I am getting "undefined" on the javascript side. Is there anything special that I need to do to the Person class to get it to work?

I annotated the following code:

```
@ExtDirectMethod(ExtDirectMethodType.STORE_READ)
@Override
public Collection<Person> getPeople(String groupId) {

    Group group = GroupManager.getGroup(groupId);
    return group.getPeopleList(); 
}
```

This is what I am using on the client side:

```
directory.getPeople(id, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Here is what app.js looks like:

```
Ext.ns('Ext.app');
Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {
    "actions":{
        "directory":[{
            "name":"getID","len":0
        },{
            "name":"getPeople","len":1
        }
    ]}‌​,
    "type":"remoting",
    "url":"/test/action/router"
};
```

Comment: I need to see the HTML and js. U have to do a link to the auto generated js on the spring.

Comment: Here is the app.js:`Ext.ns('Ext.app');Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {"actions":{"directory":[{"name":"getID","len":0},{"name":"getPeople","len":1}]},"type":"remoting","url":"/test/action/router"};`

Comment: As I mentioned I need to see the html and the js

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ExtDirectStoreResponse class? It does use a collection but also manages some useful values for use in the store.

```
@ExtDirectMethod(ExtDirectMethodType.STORE_READ)
public ExtDirectStoreResponse<Person> load()
{
    Group group = GroupManager.getGroup(groupId);
    Collection<Person> people = group.getPeopleList();

    return new ExtDirectStoreResponse<Person>(people.size(), people);
}
```

This is the approach to use when using the STORE_READ. That method annotation is expecting the request to come in matching values in the ExtDirectStoreReadRequest class. This is the reference to use when doing a store read. https://github.com/ralscha/extdirectspring/wiki/Store-Read-Method

Also, instead of calling the method directly, you would set up an ExtJs store and call

```
store.load();
```